# Visual Studio Apache Cordova Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, cordova

Just a general question as I am new to web services.  If I were to implement an application using Visual Studio Apache Cordova Server, and I wanted to store Business Logic on a server, or a connection to a SQL Server, I would need to create another project to hand these (BL Layer/ DA Layer)

Do I now need to create a Web API layer for the Cordova application to communicate with?

Or is there another way to manage server calls other than a Web API/WCF layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to keep your business logic outside application you can have in Webservice/api ,etc(one of the way)   and its easy to consume from cordova application

Cordova can directly consume your API/webservices using pure JS,angular or other frameworks.